# Where does Calendar pull emails for autocomplete?

Tags: email, contacts, calendar

I have several Gmail accounts set up on my Calendar app in OS X. Recently, though, most of the email autocomplete is not working when I'm creating a new event unless it's a contact from my personal Gmail account. I have several with different companies that all use Gmail. I have the Contacts checked for all of the associated accounts. I've attached a screenshot for reference.

Any ideas how to fix this? I've looked at both my Gmail contact lists and OS X's contact, and the calendar app does not seem to pull email address from any of it because I've cross-checked which ones autocomplete and which ones don't

I don't recall installing anything new on OS X recently.

[image]

Comment: Did this work properly at some point?

Comment: @Harv I recall setting up events and not needing to copy and paste emails into it.